# How to loop wav in web audio a certain amount of times?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I know there's an option `loop=true` on an AudioBufferSourceNode. But I just want to repeat the wav a certain number of times. For example, how might I repeat it twice?

```
var url  = 'main.wav';

var context = new AudioContext();
var source = context.createBufferSource();

source.connect(context.destination);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true); 
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(response) {

        source.buffer = response;

        source.start(0);
        source.start(source.buffer.duration); // doesn't work "cannot call start more than once."
        //source.loop = true; // this is infinite amount of times, not good

    }, function () { console.error('The request failed.'); } );
}
request.send();
```

I also tried to create a second buffer:

```
var source2 = context.createBufferSource();

// inside callback
source2.buffer = response; // same response so I don't need to load this separately
source2.start(source.buffer.duration); // doesn't work
```

But that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach with using second buffer is almost correct. You just need to use absolute start time, not relative. To obtain absolute time sum audio context's current time and duration of the sound:

```
// Play first sound now
var source1 = context.createBufferSource();
source1.buffer = response;
source1.start(context.currentTime);  // This is the same as source1.start();

// Play second sound with a delay
var source2 = context.createBufferSource();
source2.buffer = response;
source2.start(context.currentTime + response.duration);
```

This approach provides gapless playback (if your files are gapless).

You can wrap this into a simple function:

```
function play(context, buffer, delay=0) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.start(context.currentTime + delay);
    return source;
}

...

// Play the sound twice, one after another
play(context, response, 0);
play(context, response, response.duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to allow the `loop` behavior of your `source` and then schedule a callback to `stop()` the sources playback after a period of time that would allow playback of the sound file multiple times:

```
const url = 'main.wav';
const context = new AudioContext();
const source = context.createBufferSource();

// Tracks the number to playback cycles remaining
const playbackCount = 5;

source.connect(context.destination);

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = () => {

  context.decodeAudioData(request.response, (response) => {

    source.buffer = response;

    // Schedule sound to stop at future time, after which sound
    // should have played "playbackCount" number of times
    setTimeout(() => {
        source.stop();
    }, response.duration * playbackCount * 1000);

    // Enable loop behavior
    source.loop = true;

    source.start(0);
  }, () => {
    console.error('The request failed.');
  });
}
request.send();
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I'm worried that addEventListener may introduce latency though.there isn't a way to lay it directly on the timeline without the use of events?

Comment: I appreciate it, but let's leave it as what you recommended. we'll see what other people say as well.

Comment: Ok, let me know if there's anything else I can help with

Comment: If you're looping, the onended event will never fire because, well, you never end. For it to be fired, you have to call `stop` or reach the end of the buffer, or reach the duration.  See https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioscheduledsourcenode-onended

Comment: Thanks @RaymondToy

Comment: Your updated code probably doesn't do what the OP wants either because the setTimeout will get called sometime after the desired end.  Since it's looping, it will probably start playing the beginning a bit before `stop()` is called.  Generally, if you want something that is sample-accurate, `setTimeout` isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Agreed, a solution like yours offers the best precision and is also very elegant

Answer (score 1):

You can set the AudioBufferSource's `loop` to true and call

```
source.stop( ctx.currentTime + audioBuffer.duration * repeatTime )
```

```js
(async () => {  
  const url = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3';
  const buf = await fetch( url ).then( (r) => r.arrayBuffer() );
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  const audioBuffer = await ctx.decodeAudioData( buf );
  
  btn.onclick = (e) => {
    const source = ctx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.loop = true;
    source.connect( ctx.destination );
    source.start( 0 );
    source.stop( ctx.currentTime + audioBuffer.duration * inp.valueAsNumber );
  };
  btn.disabled = false;
})().catch( console.error );
```

```html
<label> repeat<input id="inp" type="number" min="1" max="20" value="5"></label>
<button id="btn" disabled>start</button>
```

Comment: nice. so every time you play it for x number of loops, looks like you need to recreate it. you can't just start/stop on the same source (?)

Comment: @foreyez yes, AudioBufferSourceNodes are meant to be used once and thrown away. Don't worry, they're very lightweight exactly for this purpose, you can create tons of it. (beware though it's not true for AudioBuffers nodes.)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the 3-arg version of [start()](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audiobuffersourcenode-start).  Something like:

```
let nReps = 2; /* Number of times to repeat the source */
let s = new AudioBufferSourceNode(context, 
             {buffer: buffer, loop: true});
s.start(startTime, 0, buffer.duration * nReps);
```